# SignalR Get Caller IP Address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Is it possible to get the caller's IP address through the HubCallerContext? Or will I have to go through HttpContext.Current...ServerVariables to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `HttpContext.Request.Current.UserHostAddress` is that `HttpContext.Request.Current` is null if you're self-hosting.

The way you get it in the current version of SignalR (the 'dev' branch as of 12/14/2012) is like so:

```
protected string GetIpAddress()
{
    var env = Get<IDictionary<string, object>>(Context.Request.Items, "owin.environment");
    if (env == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var ipAddress = Get<string>(env, "server.RemoteIpAddress");
    return ipAddress;
}

private static T Get<T>(IDictionary<string, object> env, string key)
{
    object value;
    return env.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? (T)value : default(T);
}
```

You used to be able to get it through `Context.ServerVariables`:

```
protected string GetIpAddress()
{
    var ipAddress = Context.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    return ipAddress;
}
```

That was a lot simpler, but they removed it for reasons I don't entirely understand.

Comment: Make the assumption that nobody is using the dev branch (unless explicitly stated) as it represents a point in time sha that can change anytime between now an a release.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since Owin is now fundamentally part of ASP.NET SignalR.

Answer (score 31):

With SignalR 2.0, `Context.Request` doesn't have `Items` anymore (at least not what I saw). I figured out how it works now. (You can reduce the if / else part to a ternary operator if you like.)

```
protected string GetIpAddress()
{
    string ipAddress;
    object tempObject;

    Context.Request.Environment.TryGetValue("server.RemoteIpAddress", out tempObject);

    if (tempObject != null)
    {
        ipAddress = (string)tempObject;
    }
    else
    {
        ipAddress = "";
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

Comment: A well rounded answer. In it's simplest form you could use
`Context.Request.Environment["server.RemoteIpAddress"]`

Answer (score 2):

Other way is

```
var serverVars = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.ServerVariables;
var Ip = serverVars["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26540631/) no, there is no such property in HubCallerContext.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress? See this example here: http://jameschambers.com/blog/continuous-communication-bridging-the-client-and-server-with-signalr

Don't think it's *quite* what you were hoping for, but should solve the problem nonetheless.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.