# Get client IP address in self-hosted SignalR hub

Tags: signalr

How do you go about getting the IP address of the remote client in a self-hosted SignalR hub? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044361/signalr-get-caller-ip-address), you could at one point get it using Context.ServerVariables[], but that seems to be missing from the latest version of SignalR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in poking around in the recent commits on the SignalR project (specifically [this one](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/7f4969c6a8fb32b4c1216efec9d44550c5171f02#src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubCallerContext.cs)), I spotted how to do it.

```
protected string GetIpAddress()
{
    var env = Get<IDictionary<string, object>>(Context.Request.Items, "owin.environment");
    if (env == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var ipAddress = Get<string>(env, "server.RemoteIpAddress");
    return ipAddress;
}

private static T Get<T>(IDictionary<string, object> env, string key)
{
    object value;
    return env.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? (T)value : default(T);
}
```

Comment: Asking questions about the dev branch on stackoverflow makes little sense as the masses will have no idea what you're talking about. Just an FYI

Comment: @dfowler - Granted - but I've been trying to steer clear of raising these questions as "issues" on your GitHub, as I've seen you chew other people out for trying to use them for that purpose :-). Is there a better option?

Comment: Use github when it's something like this. Nobody will be able to answer you here. The dev branch isn't something you can predict so answers will always be wrong and I rather not have them in the public

Answer (score 5):

I didn't try it with the self-hosted SignalR Hub, but with SignalR 2.0, `Context.Request` doesn't have the `Items` anymore (at least not what I saw). I figured out, how it works now. (You can reduce the if / else part to a ternary operator, if you like that.)

```
protected string GetIpAddress()
{
    string ipAddress;
    object tempObject;

    Context.Request.Environment.TryGetValue("server.RemoteIpAddress", out tempObject);

    if (tempObject != null)
    {
        ipAddress = (string)tempObject;
    }
    else
    {
        ipAddress = "";
    }

    return ipAddress;
}
```

Comment: Another form of this as a one-liner is `Context.Request.Environment["server.RemoteIpAddress"].ToString();`